C# Selenium WebDriver not respecting debugger port
I'm not entirely sure of what's going on.  I'm setting my debugger port in my ChromeOptions, however, Selenium wants to connect to whatever port it feels like.  What am I doing wrong?
                var driverInstructions = new DriverInstructions();

            driverInstructions.Driver = Driver.Chrome;
            driverInstructions.DriverLocation = @"M:\driver\127\chromedriver-win64 (5)\chromedriver-win64";
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.DebuggerAddress = "localhost:9992";
            
            sl.StartDriver(driverInstructions, false, options, false);



that looks like a call from webdriver to the wire protocol.  (or possibly it thinks it's calling to a grid)  All the modern webdrivers use wire protocol, not dev tools.  Chrome's debugger is generally for use with IDE debuggers... it uses Chrome Dev Tools Protocol, not wire protocol.
